# Reusing a component without all the reused component sharing the same state

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I have a page where you can upload some images. On this page it should be possible to upload several images, so for this sake I've created one component, with the intention of reusing it. However it seems that it shares the state with all the components that are of same type.

I've created a component called Upload. This upload component has a file and imagePreviewUrl in the state. When I render multiple instances of the component in my App, it will share this state. This means that no matter which Upload button I click, it will show the image preview in the first box. Likewise if I click any upload button again, it will overwrite the first selected image.

I'm quite new to React, so I'm not sure how I'm supposed to solve this. Should the solution be that each component create its own seperate state (if that is even possible), or do every component share the same state, and the file/imagepreviews are stored in arrays/objects in this state?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/YOLOSTEVE/pen/mmYVMB?editors=0010

```
class Upload extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            file: '',
            imagePreviewUrl: ''
        }
    }

    handleImageChange(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let file = e.target.files[0];

        if(file){
            let reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onloadend = () => {
                this.setState({
                    file: file,
                    imagePreviewUrl: reader.result
                });
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }
    }

    handleDeleteImage(){
        this.setState({
            file: '',
            imagePreviewUrl: ''
        });
    }

    render() {
        let {imagePreviewUrl} = this.state;
        let $imagePreview = null;
        if(imagePreviewUrl) {
            $imagePreview = (
                <div className="imgPreview">
                    <img src={imagePreviewUrl} />
                    <span id="file-selected"><strong>{this.state.file.name}</strong></span>
                    <p className="cancel-upload" onClick={this.handleDeleteImage.bind(this)}><span><strong>X</strong></span></p>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            $imagePreview = (
                <div className="imgPreview">
                    <div className="previewText">
                        <p><strong>Please select an Image for Preview</strong></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return(
            <div className="previewComponent">
                <p><strong>{this.props.title}</strong> ({this.props.specs})</p>

                <div className="upload-image">

                    {$imagePreview}

                    <label htmlFor="file-upload" className="custom-upload"><span>Upload</span></label>

                    <input
                        id="file-upload"
                        className="fileInput"
                        type="file"
                        onChange={(e)=>this.handleImageChange(e)}
                    />

                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Do something
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>

                   <Upload
                        title="Title 1"
                        specs="Description of first upload"
                    />
                    <Upload
                        title="Title 2"
                        specs="Description of the second upload"
                    />
                  <Upload
                        title="Title 3"
                        specs="Description of the third upload"
                    />

                    <hr/>

                    <div className="question-action-buttons">
                        <button className="save-button">Save</button>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not because components share same state. It is because you hardcoded `id` of the `file input` elements. When you render all 3 `Upload` components you have 3 input elements with same `id`. So update your code in `Upload` component as:

```
<input
      id={this.props.id}
      className="fileInput"
      type="file"
      onChange={(e)=>this.handleImageChange(e)}
                    />
```

Then in your `App` component:

```
<Upload
    id="input-1"
    title="Title 1"
    specs="Description of first upload"
/>
<Upload
    id="input-2"
    title="Title 2"
    specs="Description of the second upload"
/>
<Upload
    id="input-3"
    title="Title 3"
    specs="Description of the third upload"
/>
```

Now it should work. Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/aoguzhan/pen/YVbwbe).